# Injecting special characters in python markdown parser extension

Tags: python, markdown

I'm trying to write a tree processor extension for Python markdown, as discussed here:

https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html

As part of the extension I need to inject special characters into the document, such as n-dash or m-dash. If I use the HTML escape sequence such as `&mdash;` the Markdown layer simply escapes the ampersand, so destroys the special function of the HTML escape sequence.

Ideas welcome; the documentation is a little sparse on special case handling like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix; The Python markdown postprocessor has an undocumented escape sequence for ampersand so you can inject the HTML escapes with the ampersand escaped.

E.g. rather than injecting `&ndash;` in to the document in the extension, inject `\x02amp\x03ndash;`, and the final post-process will convert that back to a vanilla `&ndash;` in the generated HTML.

Comment: Yep, that how I'd do it. Glad you found it.